# Extract a value from an input of type string and assign to a variable

Tags: c++, getline

I have a very basic question. It's about extracting a value from a string input and then assigning this value to an int and then copying out this integer to screen. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string mystr;
    float price;
    int quantity;
    cout << "What is your name? ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    cout << "Hello Mr. " << mystr << endl;
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> price;
    cout << "Enter quantity: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream (mystr) >> quantity;
    cout << "Total price: " << quantity*price << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for purchasing our product!";
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is: when asked to enter price. Can I type "Price is 16" for example and the program is supposed to extract the 16 from the input and assign it to price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow that type of input, you would have to strip off the `Price is` portion before you can then read the `16` portion. Easiest way to do that is to simply put the input into a `stringstream` and call its `>>` operator in a loop until you reach a number or the end of the stream, eg:

```
cout << "Enter price: ";
getline(cin, mystr);

stringstream ss(mystr);
do
{
    if (ss >> price)
        break;
}
while (!ss.eof());

if (!ss)
{
    // no price provided, do something...
}
```